# Regular and irregular points on the boundary for Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

If we take unit ball which is punctured at the origin and consider the origin as the boundary point, then why is it so that the origin is a irregular point if d>1 but regular for d=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the zero set of Brownian Motion intersects $[0,t]$ at infinitely many points (this follows, for instance, by the law of the iterated logarithm). This proves that $(-a,b)\setminus \{0\}$ is a regular set for one-dimensional Brownian Motion.

For two dimensions or higher, you can simply pick a sequence $t_n\to 0$ and note that $\mathbb{P}^0(X_t\neq 0\;\forall t>0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}^0(X_t\neq 0\;\forall t>t_n)$. By the Markov Property, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}^0(X_t\neq 0\;\forall t>t_n)=\mathbb{E}^0 [\mathbb{P}^{X_{t_n}}[X_t\neq 0\; \forall t>0]]
$$
Now, by Brownian scaling and rotation invariance, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}^{x}[X_t\neq 0\; \forall t>0]=\mathbb{P}^{e_1}[X_t\neq 0\; \forall t>0]
$$
for all $x\neq 0$. Hence, since $X_{t_n}\neq 0$ almost surely, we get that $ \mathbb{P}^0(X_t\neq 0\;\forall t>t_n)=\mathbb{P}^{e_1}[X_t\neq 0\; \forall t>0]=1$, where the last equality follows from the fact that we're in dimension two or greater. If you don't know this result, you can see the following for a solution in three dimensions or higher ([Modulus 3-dim. Brownian motion convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469400/modulus-3-dim-brownian-motion-convergence/3469568#3469568)). The two dimensional case is similar but the harmonic function involved is a logarithm.

Hence, if $\tau_{B'}$ and $\tau_B$ denote the first exit times from the punctured and the  unpunctured balls respectively, we get
$$
\mathbb{P}^0[\tau_{B'}=\tau_B]=1
$$
and $\mathbb{P}^0[\tau_B=0]=0$. Since $0$ is on the boundary of the punctured ball, this implies that $B'$ is not regular for Brownian Motion.